# Always-On listener not working correctly

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, failover, listener

I have an Always-On architecture with two nodes and two AG. One of AG working correctly but other AG's listener only directs to the primary node. When I fail it to the secondary node, the application goes down. When I check everything looks fine.

`select * from sys.dm_tcp_listener_states`
`select * from sys.availability_group_listeners`
`select * from sys.availability_group_listener_ip_addresses`

[image]

Comment: Please add the listener definition (output of the DMVs you listed is fine) and type (network name, distributed network name), the environment you're running in (on-prem, AWS, Azure, etc), the output of `netstat -ano -p tcp` from the new primary replica where it isn't working.

Comment: If AG is working correct, could also be the application not having a retry mechanism. Failovers cut current connections and the application has to reconnect.